# Help locating the virtualbox export?

Tags: virtualbox, find

I just did this

```
VBoxManage export foo_to_be_export --output bar.ova
```

But then I forgot to setup the default path. However, it shows it's 100%. I couldn't find this image now.

I tried

```
sudo find / -name bar.ova
sudo find . -name bar.ova
```

and none finds anything.

The first one seems to take forever (8 mins already...) so I just stopped it.

Does anyone know the default path? How can I find out?

Comment: Run the export again, and see if it tell you anything.

Comment: On *Export Appliance-> NameofVM -> Next* your export path will be displayed, just cancel then and see if it's there.

Comment: Thanks. It is now in home directory. But the first one was not. It was missing... and also, the output was the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `find` on `/` will search everything on your computer, including any mounted drives. To prevent this from happening, run:

```
find / -xdev -name bar.ova
```

By the way, you only need to run it with `sudo` if you ran the `VBoxManage --export ...` command with `sudo`. Otherwise, it's extremely unlikely that `VBoxManage` could have created a file somewhere you can't read from. You'll get plenty of "access denied" messages running `find` on `/` without `sudo` ...but that's not really a problem. If you want to log the results (but not error messages) to a file in your home directory, you can do this:

```
find / -xdev -name bar.ova | tee -a ~/find-results.log
```

If you have a separate partition for `/home` (which only happens if you set it up that way when you install Ubuntu, or deliberately migrate `/home` to a separate partition after installation), then `find` on `/` with `-xdev` won't search `/home` (which contains your home directory). The simplest and easiest solution to this is to do a separate `find` operation on `/home`:

```
find /home -xdev -name bar.ova
```

Or just on your home directory in `/home`, if you don't think you could've put it in another user's home directory:

```
find ~ -xdev -name bar.ova
```

You may want to leave off `-xdev` in these cases, though it's possible you (or other users) have FUSE or GVFS shares mounted inside home directories. (It's also possible a file got saved into one of those shares...)

With `-xdev`, when running `find` on `/`, it will still take a while, but it will complete eventually.

**Something else you may want to try is to run `sudo updatedb`, wait for that to finish, and then run `locate bar.ova`.**

Comment: Thanks for the complete walk through with various commands here. I tried `updatedb` as well but it shows only one. I guess something went really bad that it is now missing. I guess for now I will give up on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When I used the example you've given, substituting one of my virtual box vms like so:

```
chris@4314-APPWP:~$ VBoxManage export "Ubuntu LTP" --output bar.ova
```

The bar.ova file was generated in my home directory.

```
chris@4314-APPWP:~$ ls -lah bar.ova 
-rw------- 1 chris chris 1.3G Jun  7 14:26 bar.ova
chris@4314-APPWP:~$ pwd
/home/chris
chris@4314-APPWP:~$
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried it again and it is in home directory. But the one I did first time was missing. The image is 1.9GB, and we run backup on this machine. It will be a disaster to not find out if it has been created or not. Is there a better find/grep command that I am not familiar with that can trace down? I tried `*.ova` as well..... Thanks

Comment: @user1012451 Besides `\*.ova` (because if there are `.ova` files in the current directory, the shell will expand `*.ova` into a space-delimited list of them, and then the output of `find` will be strictly limited to those files instead of any other `.ova` files anywhere) ...you can also try `-iname` instead of `-name` (in case there is differing capitalization in the filename or `.ova` suffix).

Comment: @itnet 7 Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To find a file that's lost somewhere on your filesystem, run the following commands.

```
sudo updatedb
locate filename.ext
```

---

#### Explanation

`updatedb` - Updates the database used by locate.
`locate` - You guessed it. It locates files.